# Finding the column name of row which has highest value while comprehending the row based on max column value

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dataframe

I'm pretty new to Python. Im trying to define a function for the below set of data.
[Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yu96qRyyeN-M10UzkE04mn1d9TWCWdCSvrfThxbXVxA/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm first looking for the max value in `cell 3`. Based on this max value I'm checking which column given in the last 8 columns of the data has the highest value against it.

For example, As per the given data, Max value in `cell 3 is 1470758`. Now I'm checking which columns from  column `cell 9` to `cell 16` has the highest value against this max value. In the case of this sample data the answer should be cell 10 with a value of 7201. So the output should be cell 10.

Here's my code:

```
def winner(filename):
    data=pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
    maxC=data.npop.max()
    while data.loc[data['npop']]==maxC:
        data3=data.iloc[:,-8:].max()
#missing code
winner("demo.csv")
```

Please help. I didn't understand what I should be writing in the missing code section.

Comment: provide data in text not as image, so others can easily copy it

Comment: Edited the data link.

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if it works or you find any issue.

Comment: Yes it works..but can u please tell me if my way of doing is wrong...or is it too primitive.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you were doing there. What is `npop` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line by line explanation of code is given with comments.

Try this :

```
def winner(filename):
    df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')  # Read the csv into dataframe.
    column_names = list(df.columns.values) # Get list of column names

    max_col3_index = df['col3'].idmax()  # this will return the index of max value in `col3` column.

    row_data = df.loc[max_col3_index, column_names[-8:]]  # get series of data present in last 8 columns at above index.

    final_column_name = row_data.idxmax()  # Get the name of column having max value in above series.

    print(final_column_name)
```